# cx-freeze not able to build python containing urllib and bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, cx-freeze

I have made a script in python using urllib abd bs4 and i want to make it executable using 
cx-freeze.But I am not able to do it. It shows the following error:

```
Missing modules:
? Carbon imported from plistlib
? Carbon.File imported from plistlib
? Carbon.Files imported from plistlib
? MacOS imported from platform
? OpenSSL.SSL imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? _emx_link imported from os
? _scproxy imported from urllib
? bs4.builder imported from bs4
? builtins imported from requests.packages.urllib3.packages.six
? cchardet imported from bs4.dammit
? ce imported from os
? chardet imported from bs4.dammit
? fcntl imported from subprocess
? gestalt imported from platform
? http imported from requests.compat
? http.client imported from requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool
? http.cookies imported from requests.compat
? iconv_codec imported from bs4.dammit
? java.lang imported from platform
? ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification imported from requests.packages.urllib3.
contrib.pyopenssl
? ndg.httpsclient.subj_alt_name imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.
pyopenssl
? netbios imported from uuid
? org.python.core imported from copy, pickle
? os.path imported from os, requests.certs, shlex
? os2 imported from os
? os2emxpath imported from os
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from getpass, posixpath
? pyasn1.codec.der imported from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? queue imported from requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool
? riscos imported from os
? riscosenviron imported from os
? riscospath imported from os
? rourl2path imported from urllib
? simplejson imported from requests.compat
? termios imported from getpass
? urllib.parse imported from requests.compat, requests.packages.urllib3.request
? urllib.request imported from requests.compat
? vms_lib imported from platform
? win32api imported from platform
? win32con imported from platform
? win32pipe imported from platform
? win32wnet imported from uuid
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platfo
rm.
```

I have imported bs4, requests, re, time in my program.
What should I do?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the output you included. What error do you get from the binary, or is it not producing a binary?

Comment: Are you including the libraries in your setup file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If builds fail because they aren't automatically including imported libraries you can add them into the package section of your setup.py. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096977/cx-freeze-include-modules-automatically) post.

setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["bs4, urllib, requests"], "excludes": [""]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "my-app",
        version = "0.9.0",
        description = "Copyright 2013",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("my_module.py", base=base)])
```

You likely might only have to specify bs4, most modules should be found and included automatically. [BS4 is known to have issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509612/no-module-named-bs4-when-using-cx-freeze) so just try including that at first.

[here](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html) is the docs for cx_freeze.

Comment: And what about requests, because cx-freeze cannot find urllib also?

Comment: just add them after bs4 in the provided code separated by **,**

Comment: after including bs4 the error in cmd still appears however when running the exe it shows an error message and it says "no module named builder".

Comment: That is a part of the BS4 library, make sure it is referenced correctly in your code. You might even need to re-install BS4 from pip? maybe add `from bs4 import builder` to your code and re-freeze?

Comment: [Here is a previous post pertaining to the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509612/no-module-named-bs4-when-using-cx-freeze)

Comment: I have included bs4,requests,platform,os,urllib. But it does not help.

Comment: Here is the full error when i run the exe:                                    -traceback(most recent call last):
file
"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_freeze-4.3.3-py2.7-win32.egg\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py",line 27,in<module>
 exec(code,m._dict_)
File "finalhpc.py", line 2, in <module>
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bs4\_init_.py", line 29,in <module>
ImportError:No module named builder

Comment: It's been noted in other posts that it is due to bs4 being installed as an egg and Uninstaller and reinstalling it through pip has been recommended. I can't see anything else to try. sounds like you've done everything else you could.

Comment: I reinstalled bs4 some of the errors have gone.Please look at the remaining ones:                                                        -traceback(most recent call last):
file
"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_freeze-4.3.3-py2.7-win32.egg\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py",line 27,in<module>
 exec(code,m._dict_)
File "finalhpc.py", line 8, in <module>
EOFError:EOF when reading a line

Comment: Is it outputting an exe? If so run it from the command line so you can see the full output of the errors. It looks like it is failing when it gets to line 8 of your finalhpc.py file.

Comment: yes, it shows an error when i am taking in an input, userid=raw_input("Enter the userid\n")

Comment: you can put that in a try statement and [except the EOF error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1092300) ,  or it might be the line isn't indented properly within a loop?